# Find a hacked directory in a Drupal site

Tags: drupal

A Drupal site I manage started showing a standard Google malware warning on one of the directories.

I see the suspicious code in the page source, and need to be able to remove it.

Not being familiar with Drupal, I can't determine where to locate the directory and a page where the code is.

I used Google Webmaster tools to determine the malicious snippet. All I want is remove it, but can't figure out where from.

Would appreciate advice from Drupal experts.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for ServerFault.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not sure. Could you please tell me why? I'm not asking how to manage a server, but rather, my question is about standard Drupal architecture. I'm absolutely unfamiliar with Drupal, though, so I may be wrong. Would appreciate your further suggestions.

Comment: This is a programming site and your question is not a programming question.

Comment: I am a little unsure if you are correct. You are saying that the directory structure of a web application doesn't have anything to do with programming?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Hacked module to find out if the hacker has hacked your Drupal. https://drupal.org/project/hacked